# Change hotkey volume indicator

Tags: sound, gnome, customization

Im using ubuntu 12.04 with gnome shell everything is fine, but I find a bit ugly the image used when I change the sound via fn keys:
http://s15.postimage.org/xn01s5vsb/icon.png

Is there any way to modify this image or any gnome-shell extension that changes it?

Answer (score 1):

It should be using the larger version. Make sure you have `gnome-icon-theme-full` installed if you're using gnome-shell.

You can change the theme you're using in `dconf-editor` by changing the `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/icon-theme` entry to be `gnome`. It looks like you are currently using the Humanity theme (or ubuntu-mono-dark, which is the Ubuntu default), and it does not provide high resolution versions of that icon. The lack of high resolution versions of the icons in any of the Humanity or ubuntu-mono icon themes may be considered a bug, and you should report it in Launchpad.

Comment: It is already installed: `gnome-icon-theme-full is already the newest version.` Also the bright indicator is using its large version